# The exterior measure of a closed cube is equal to its volume (specific discuss)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

"[The exterior measure of a closed cube is equal to his volume.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383115/the-exterior-measure-of-a-closed-cube-is-equal-to-his-volume)" is the original question and we can also find the proof in the book `real analysis (by Stein 2nd edition), p.11`.

**My question is, what is the role of "$\epsilon$" in the proof?**

I can prove this in the following: (the proof for $|Q| \leq m_*(Q)$)

1. Let $Q$ be arbitrarily covered by $Q\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_j$.
2. By monotonicity, $|Q|\leq |\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_j|$.
3. By subadditivity, $|\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_j|\leq \sum_1^{\infty}|Q_j|$
4. SInce the covering is arbitrary, so $|Q| \leq \text{inf}\sum_1^{\infty}|Q_j|=m_*(Q)$

**Can I prove this in that way, without using $\epsilon$ ?**

I think the spirit of the proof is the $\epsilon$; however, it seems reasonable in the proof I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. First, the notation $|\bigcup_jQ_j|$ doesn't even make sense; $|E|$ is defined if $E$ is a *cube*, not for arbirary $E$. So steps 2 and 3 don't make much sense. The monotonicity and subadditivity you refer to are properties of $m_*$, not $|\cdot|$.

The crux of the matter is showing that $|Q|\le\sum_j|Q_j|$. But how do you prove that?

It seems obvious. But it also seems obvious for intervals of *rationals*, and in that context it's not true - it's easy to see that there exist intervals $I_j$ such that $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q\subset\bigcup_j I_j$ but $\sum_j|I_j|<1$.

The point to the actual proof is to replace the $Q_j$ by slightly larger *open* cubes; now compactness shows that $Q$ is covered by finitely many of those open cubes. But the larger open cubes are larger; the point to that $\epsilon$ is to make sure that they're not *too much* larger...

Comment: David, in the book, the authors first start with $\epsilon > 0$ but later merely prove that $|Q| \leq (1+\epsilon) \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |Q_j|$. So how do we drop $\epsilon$ since all this proves is that we can get arbitrarily close to “slightly larger” but not to “exactly equal”.